# babel-polyfill not working in browsers

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, redux, babeljs

I'm using webpack to transpile my React app, and everything seems to be working nicely in Chrome. Here is the entry from my webpack.config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    bundle: [ 'babel-polyfill', './client/index.js', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr' ],
    vendor: [ 'react' ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../', 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx' ]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js/,
        loaders: [ 'react-hot', 'babel' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return [ autoprefixer({ browsers: [ 'last 2 versions' ] }) ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('dist', 'vendor.js'),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
}
```

My app works and runs perfectly in Chrome, but in any other browser (Firefox, Safari, Chrome mobile, etc) I get an error seemingly related to babel-polyfill not being included.

In Firefox, this is `SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier`

Also, I know that I am including `babel-polyfill` correctly because I am able to make the browser run into the error: `Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed` by including the polyfill in two ways at the same time.

What could be causing this?? I'm baffled, and somewhat impressed that Chrome works if `babel-polyfill` isn't included correctly.

**EDIT:**
I thought that a `.babelrc` was satisfactory for babel to compile, but maybe I'm wrong. Here's my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015-node4", "stage-2", "react" ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Actually.. I think you're missing some presets, like `es2015`

Comment: You still need to transpile your ES6 code. Babel-polyfill is just shimming builtins.

Comment: @azium I'm using babel-loader, which I thought got the job done. Maybe I am wrong - my webpack.config and .babelrc are above.

I opted to use a .babelrc file instead of query in my babel-loader.

Comment: es2015-node4? could that be it?

Comment: I just tried with es2015 and stage-0 as well, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: did we get any far with this issue?